# Odds of rolling m or more 6's if you roll a 6 sided die n times

Tags: probability

If you roll a six-sided die $n$ times the odds of never rolling a 6 are $(\frac 56)^n$ and so, the odds of rolling one or more 6s are $1-(\frac56)^n$.

Can this be generalized to a situation where you desire $m$ 'hits'?

The specific situation I started thinking about this is one where the odds of success are $1$ in $10$, and $3$ successes are needed. I assumed that determining the odds of 3 hits after $n$ attempts would be fairly simple but I hit a wall pretty quickly (I have a pretty poor stats background).

I'm less concerned about that specific case, but more interested in: is there a simple solution to this problem in general?

Comment: Sure.  This is just a binomial process with success probability $\frac 16$ so the standard formulas apply.  If your numbers are large, then the usual normal approximation can be quite accurate.

Comment: Wow thanks,  I love math but have never driven deep into the stat side!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments, this is a typical application of the [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

The Binomial distribution has two parameters:

- $n$ is the number of trials, e.g. how often you throw the die
- $p$ is the success probability of one trial, e.g. the probability of throwing a six.

Given these two parameters you can easily compute the probability of $m$ successes in $n$ trials by:

$$
\Bbb P (\text{exactly} \ m \ \text{successes}) = {{n}\choose {m}} p^m (1 -p)^{n-m}.
$$